# Unable to Delete Using Laravel's Policy

Tags: php, laravel

I am logged in as user2 and would like to see the delete button on user2's review (screenshot). However, the button did not appear. I am using Laravel's policy.

[image]

I have attached my blade code below:

```
@foreach($reviews as $review)
{{-- <div id="review_card" class="card" style="width: 18rem;">     --}}
<div id="review_card" class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{ $review->title }}</h5>
    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">User {{ $review->user_id }}</h6>
    <p class="card-text">{{ $review->review }}</p>
    <a href="/cimb_editreview/{{ $review->id }}" class="card-link">Edit</a>
    {{-- <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a> --}}

    @can('delete', $review)
    <a href="{{"delete/".$review['id']}}" class="card-link">Delete</a>
    @endcan
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my ReviewPolicy code snippet:

```
public function delete(User $user, Review $review)
    {
        return $user->id === $review->user_id;
    }
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::get('/delete/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@deleteReview')->middleware('user');
```

And lastly, here's the AuthServiceProvider:

```
protected $policies = [
            'App\Models\Review' => 'App\Policies\ReviewPolicy',
        ];
```

To my understanding, the deletability of the review lies in ReviewPolicy and that was where I tried to tweak the code, but to no success. Not exactly sure where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... can you change `===` to `==` and see if it changes? seeing if you are comparing 2 different types (int, string)

Comment: @sta `===` is a logical operation so it evaluates to a `bool`

Comment: @lagbox  I tried it here, with `==` and `===` too, but don't get any output https://rextester.com/FQFJZ2273

Comment: btw how did you define this policy is for that model? not sure what version of Laravel you are using ... ruling out that the policy is not being used at all

Comment: That's what I'm wondering, how does `@can('delete', $review)` know to use `ReviewPolicy@delete`?

Comment: @if(auth()->user()->can('delete', $review))
   <a href="{{"delete/".$review['id']}}" class="card-link">Delete</a>
@endif

Comment: @DigitalDrifter in general or just in this situation?

Comment: Specifically this case. I'm assuming it's being registered in a service provider.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter yea not sure, if its a newer version it might be auto wired ... but i would like to know

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the replies. I've just edited the post to include the code from AuthServiceProvider. I'm using Laravel Framework 8.13.0 btw.

Comment: did you adjust the `===` to `==` in the policy method? and are you sure that is your model and it isn't `App\Models\Review`?

Comment: Firstly yes, I changed to == and it did not return anything. Secondly, you're right; the model is App\Models\Review. I've made the change but the issue still persist.

Comment: You can add `dd($review->toArray());` to the policy method to see if it's actually getting called and with the correct value.

Comment: Yes, it gets called with all the column values. I'd want to display the delete button where the logged in user's id matches the review's userid.

array:9 [▼
  "id" => 5
  "user_id" => 3
  "bank_name" => null
  "product_name" => "Ar Rihla Regular Savings Account"
  "title" => "High Hibah Rate"
  "review" => "Love the account. Ethical saving with high hibah rate."
  "rating" => "5"
  "created_at" => "2020-11-11T02:06:16.000000Z"
  "updated_at" => "2020-11-11T02:06:16.000000Z"
]